# JavaFX Binary Search - Issue with loop

Tags: java, search, binary, javafx

I have 6 text fields (number1-6) in JavaFX and another textfield named "textfieldLF" that is the number that the user is searching for. I am trying to make a JavaFX program for searching between 6 different numbers using the binary search algorithm, but for some reason it's not working.

I used the algorithm from Wikipedia. I checked the indexes of arrays to make sure they are right, because the first if condition and statement works perfectly alone. It's only when it wants to determine what change it has to make to the midpoint that I think it has a problem in.

The code:

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // First and last indexes declaration
        int imin = 1;
        int imax = 6;

        // Declare array for user inputs
        String[] NumbersArray = {number1.getText(), number2.getText(), number3.getText(), number4.getText(), number5.getText(), number6.getText()};

        // What to find? Get input from user
        String ToFind = textfieldLF.getText();

        // Match Index
        String MatchID;

        // Match Found? Boolean
        boolean MatchFound = false;

        // Find midpoint
        int imid = (int) ceil((double)((imin + imax) / 2));

        while (MatchFound = false)
        {
            // Try to find match in midpoint position
            if (NumbersArray[imid].equals(ToFind))
            {
                System.out.println("Match #" + (imid + 1));
                MatchFound = true;
            } else if(Integer.parseInt(NumbersArray[imid]) < Integer.parseInt(ToFind)) {
                imin = imid + 1;
                MatchFound = false;
            } else {
                imax = imid - 1;
                MatchFound = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

I would appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: Are the values from the number fields guarantied to be sorted?? I also don't see where you exit the loop, if the value you search is not in the array. Are there any checks preventing the user from typing in unsorted values in the number fields and non-existing values in the textfieldLF textfield?

Comment: Well in my test I tried it with numbers from 1 to 6 (in fields 1 to 6 respectively) and also the other way round but it didn't print out Match # or anything. I am just trying to get it to work in a basic way, guaranteed that user will only enter a sorted list but there are no checks. Doesn't it have to work even if I don't exit the loop? Thanks for your reply by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work, since you never change `imid`. It's also no binary search, since doesn't reduce the index range by half every step.

Move

```
int imid = (int) ceil((double)((imin + imax) / 2));
```

inside the loop(to the beginning of the loop body). You still have to add a way to exit the loop.

Also your start indices are wrong. The index range of your array is 0-5 and not 1-6.